# Javascript: Find the deepest object and return a value from it?

Tags: javascript

WITHOUT Jquery, how could I find the deepest object in an array of object?

So I have an object, which can have many children, sometimes 1 child, sometimes 10 children, each of those children may have several children.

**I want to find what the property 'label' of the single deepest object is and return that.**

I don't want to find the deepest object that has a label property, this is different; I want to find the absolute deepest object and then return what that label property says (might be blank or nonexistent sometimes).

Any ideas?

EDIT:
There will *always* be a deepest object, there will never be an even number of children to the starting main object

EDIT2:
I don't have anything resembling working code, but here is a bit more description:

```
Object1 = ({ label: Hello, friend: Object2 }) 
Object2 = ({ label: HJM });
```

My desired result would be `HJM`

EDIT 3: An even more complex dataset

```
var data = [
    {label:1 },
    {John:2 },
    {Jack:3 },
    {label:4, friend: [
        {label:5 },
        {label:6 },
        {Alex:7 , friend: [
            {label:8 }]
    ]}
];
```

The result of `myMagicFunction(data)` would ideally be  **'8'**

Comment: What if there are more objects at the same depth, what would be the *single deepest object* then ?

Comment: Some code, showing us what you're working with and what you've tried, would be helpful.

Comment: @adeneo Thx, there will actually always be an deepest object.  I edited the question to reflect that now

Comment: So you're starting with an array of objects, are there any more arrays in those objects ?

Comment: @j08691 My code right now is OT to my question, the code I have been working with doesn't work at all because what it is doing is successfully finding the deepest child that has a **label** property.  So for me its stopping prematurely as some of the middle level children have **label** properties.  I just want to get to the end of the children list and see what is there

Comment: @adeneo Yup, it can get very deep with children that will themselves be objects, some of which have a **label** property, some of which don't.  So, I'm trying to march down the list to find the deepest object and then return the Obj.label property

Comment: So you need to detect the index of the array where is located the deepest object and the final object at this index

Comment: What kind of children? Are you talking about DOM nodes? Or object properties? How do you define "deepest object"?

Comment: @Oriol these are object properties, so Object1({label:Hello,friend:Object2}).  Object2({label:HJM});   My desired result would be 'HJM'

Comment: @Mark What about `{a:{label:1},b:{label:2}}`?

Comment: @Oriol It will never be even, there will always be an uneven # of children, so to continue what you are saying it would realistically be {a:{label:1, friend:{label:3},b:{label:2}}

Comment: I don't see how parity matters. Anyways, what should `{a:{label:1},b:{label:2},c:{label:3}}` output? There isn't an unique deepest object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDeepestObject(obj){
  var children = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key]) 
      children.push(getDeepestObject(obj[key]));
  });
  if(!children.length){ return { obj:obj, level:0 }; }
  else { 
     var deepestChild = {level:-1};
     children.forEach(function(child){
       if(child.level > deepestChild.level)
         deepestChild = child; 
     });
     return deepestChild;
  }
}


var o = {
  e: {
      f: {
         j: { label: 'hello'}
      },
      r: {}
   },
   a: {
      l:{}
   },
   r: {}
}

console.log(getDeepestObject(o).obj.label)
```